# Application starts using Logback after using Apache CXF

Tags: java, soap, cxf, log4j2

In my application, once I added SOAP interfaces, it is trying to use `Logback`. As we do not have `Logback`, it is throwing exception of `ClassNotFound`.

I added following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have following dependency of logging.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have added following config to configure endpoint.

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ReservationService reservationService;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint reservationEndpoint(){
        Endpoint endpoint = new EndpointImpl(getBus(), reservationService);
        endpoint.publish("/Reservation");
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public Bus getBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

}
```

After this, I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I am not able to find how is it using `Logback`. Also, I configured `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` to following value: `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger`. Still, it is using `Logback`. Earlier, my application was using `Log4j2`. I want to continue to use the existing logging system.

On further debug, I found that using `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger` property while running, we can control the logging class. I tried `org.slf4j.core.Logger` and log4j2 classes. They faced error of No such method exception.

I want to solve:

1. How to force application use existing logging system?
2. Even if it requires `Logback` dependency, how to use `Log4j2`.

Answer (score 0):

add the  exclusion for all spring-boot starter depenencies not just for web

```
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
```

Comment: Problem is still there. Now, it is on class `ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.TurboFilter`.